# Why do some initial webpage requests route to my router?

Tags: macos, networking, router, browser

When I start using my internet on some device (laptop, desktop, iPod, iPhone) some of the initial request like `google.com` or `facebook.com` route to my routers config page or sometimes Google gives me a "404 not found" page.

After some time has passed, the internet starts working normally. This happens every time. Why?

I'm in Germany and using internet from an ISP called M-Net on OSX 10.6.7. My modem is a 
AVM Fritz!Box 2110 ADSL2+ with an integrated firewall.

-----edit-----
Due to some problems I cant recover the password on my router. But I can still use the internet. The problem happens with all websites  and comes and goes randomly. I have three other people using the same internet connection. 'Some time' is totally random 5 mins to 1 hour. When this happens I cant ping google.com from terminal.

Comment: unfortunately all infromation is in german and my german is not so good, http://www.dslweb.de/dsl-hardware-132-AVM-Fritz-Box-2110.htm

Comment: Not much interesting there to see (I could translate for you if needed) -- Does this happen to all websites? While this happens, can you `ping` other devices in your network? What is "some time", are we talking about seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: Perhaps your router disconnects from the internet after some period of inactivity, and only reconnects on next request? That should be configurable (and even possible to be disabled) on the router; alas, without access to it you'd be out of luck :(

Answer (score -1):

> Due to some problems I cant recover the password on my router.

Have you tried a factory reset of the router?

Usually done with the router on,
press the reset button for 30 seconds,
the router should be reset to factory defaults.
Power down the router wait a minute, then power on the router.

You should be able access the router with the default user id and password.

Bill